# javascript (lack of) concurrency[threads] (non)issues

Tags: javascript, multithreading

This is not much of a question, but more like a sudden enlightenment.

So I have two initialization functions which are rune consecutively in javascript like this:

```
object1.Init();
object2.Init();
```

So I thought, to make them "faster" I could try to call both of them simultaneously so that they can run simultaneously by this method:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    object1.Init();
}, 0);

setTimeout(function() {
    object2.Init();
}, 0);
```

My rationale was that if i do this, both functions will start "simultaneously" and then each take their time to end (one may end in 300ms and the other in 500ms).

Wow that was a good idea I thought initially, but then i realized that both **Init()** functions use a global variable, so I got scared to death that one could be altered by the other and thus cause catastrophic results.

So I ended up doing this simple test in order to see if my assumption was right.

```
var cnt = 0;
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;

setTimeout(function() {
    t1 = new Date().getTime();
    for (cnt=0; cnt<1000000000; cnt++) {
        x1++;
    }
    t2 = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<br>" + (t2-t1) + " milliseconds " + x1 + "#" + t1 + "#" + t2;
}, 0);

setTimeout(function() {
    var t3 = new Date().getTime();
    for (cnt=0; cnt<1000000000; cnt++) {
        x2++;
    }
    var t4 = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += "<br>" + (t4-t3) + " milliseconds " + x2 + "#" + t3 + "#" + t4;
}, 0);
```

whose result was:

```
2504 milliseconds 1000000000#1379702812419#1379702814923
2514 milliseconds 1000000000#1379702814923#1379702817437
```

which what really told me is:

a) there is no such thing as concurrency in javascript since the second loop starts AFTER the first one ends

b) thus i'm safe, the global variable won't be affected

c) there is no point in running the two init() functions by using settimeout() like this

I guess that a) is due to the fact that javascript is single threaded which is really a shame ( yes i know about web workers ).

Comment: Side note - don't use global variables. They're evil.

Comment: Yeah, this is more like a blog post rather than a question.

Comment: You should split this post into a question plus an answer, for it to fit Stack Exchange.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I only use them as counters ( in order to avoid declaring counters in each function )

Answer (score 1):

> a) there is no such thing as concurrency in javascript since the second loop starts AFTER the first one ends

Right, as you said yourself, JavaScript runs single-threaded, and there's no such thing as simultaneous operations.

> b) thus i'm safe, the global variable won't be affected

Yes, you're safe.

> c) there is no point in running the two init() functions by using settimeout() like this

Indeed...

Comment: Which makes *me* ask: are you really asking a question here?

Comment: I guess my question was: if my 3 realizations (a,b,c) were right, which i guess they are, and as you pointed out indeed they are.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about "javascript" globally but discussing it in the context of a browser.

I encourage you to check out the [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.  I use it in Node.  It performs multiple operations "simultaneously", using totally standard processor slicing. It may technically be a single thread but not in the way in which you're (probably) used to it, with each line blocking and nothing happening until the previous line has executed.  Anytime you have an async callback you will have behavior that simulates multiple concurrent threads.

To experiment with this, write an HTTP request (or 7) and watch their callbacks come back at various non-blocking times.  Or try the file system calls, or the SQL calls, or anything else that ventures out to engage with the environment. In every situation you wind up with "multi-threaded" acting behavior.

Comment: There is a difference between asynchronous and multi-threaded. Javascript is, except for WebWorkers, single-threaded – *period*.

Comment: Ingo, you can argue the semantics till the cows come home, but to say that Javascript is "single-threaded" is incredibly misleading.  If you have one processor then *everything is technically single threaded and the processor fakes multi-threading by taking turns with each process, giving everyone a little time slice.  If you tell someone that their program is single threaded then they immediately assume that every line blocks and that no two things can happen concurrently which is fundamentally not true in Javascript... you can have all sorts of simultaneous behavior.

Comment: No one would think that every line blocks if they know it's asynchronous. That's what it means. Multi-threading and asynchronous *are* different. In true multi-threading you have way more problems that you don't have in asynchronousity, i.e. you don't have them in Javascript. Javascript being single-threaded is not an argument, it's a fact. A fact you can confirm in many other SO posts.

Comment: @IngoBürk, I'm not disputing that fact. I'm trying to help the OP understand something that he appears to be misunderstanding. His question suggests that concurrent processing is not possible in javascript. I'm showing him that in fact it's very much a part of the language. All I'm saying is that the semantics of multi-threading vs. async are confusing and irrelevant to THIS question.

Comment: I think since he is specifically asking (sort of) about this topic, distinguishing between asynchronous and multi-threading is indeed important. You can tell him about asynchronous processes simply without talking about single-/multi-threading. Especially so since he stated himself that he knows that it is single-threaded, so telling him "nothing single-threaded about it" is actually quite misleading, suggesting that it isn't – even though it is.

Comment: ok, I've edited. hope you're happy :)